# How and where java compier stores .class file

Tags: java, classpath

**Statement**: Java compiler stores .class files in path specified in CLASSPATH environment variable

My question is if above is true then when we compile any java file we find the.class file in that folder where .java file resides

Then how fisrt statement is true and why both statement arent contradicting?

Comment: The classpath is irrelevant regarding where newly compiled classes will be created. Beyond that, this is a really basic question, so please do some more research before posting future questions.

Comment: So that statement is false ? I am trying my best but as a beigner two statements created a dilema for me

Comment: Yes, the initial statement is false.

Comment: ok thanks a lot  for help